# C++ <-> C# Named Pipe Communication

Tags: c#, c++, windows, pipe, ipc

Implementing IPC on windows using named pipes.

C# named pipe server and C++ named pipe client.
Losing the first character when sending data from the C++ client to the C# server.

For example, if "This is a test message" is sent from the C++ client, the server will receive "his is a test message". Below is revelant code.

C++ Client Code

```
    success = WriteFile(
    pipe,
    guiMsg,
    PIPE_BUFFER_SIZE,
    &bytesWritten,
    NULL);
```

C# server code

```
main()
    {
        NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer =
            new NamedPipeServerStream(@"ZVMonitorPipe", PipeDirection.InOut, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.Asynchronous);

        StreamString ss = new StreamString(pipeServer);
        ...
        ...
        string input = ss.ReadString();
        Console.WriteLine(input);
        ...
        ...
    }

public class StreamString
    {
        private Stream ioStream;
        private UnicodeEncoding streamEncoding;

        public StreamString(Stream ioStream)
        {
            this.ioStream = ioStream;
            streamEncoding = new UnicodeEncoding();
        }

        public string ReadString()
        {
            int len = 0;

            len = ioStream.ReadByte() * 64;
            len += ioStream.ReadByte();
            byte[] inBuffer = new byte[len];
            ioStream.Read(inBuffer, 0, len);

            return streamEncoding.GetString(inBuffer);
        }
...
...
...
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Use DCOM instead.

Comment: Crom. I forgot about DCOM. Thanks @Ben , you may have just solved a totally unrelated problem I was working on.

Comment: It looks like the read code is reading a length prefixed message (with the length encoded in 2 bytes).  The sending  code does not show how / if the length is prefixed on to the message.

Comment: @Ðаn he can't use WCF for that. There's no WCF for C++.

Comment: @Ben I have some hands on experience programming DCOM in C++. Would not recommend the technology to anyone.

Comment: @Soonts if you are having trouble with it then maybe ask a question on SO. Lots of people will be able to help you, including me.

Answer (score 1):

The IO looks functional. You’ve forgot `WaitForConnection` in the server, and you’re ignoring all return codes, e.g. each `ReadByte()` can return you -1 instead of the data.

Very likely, the problem is the code that prepares the buffer to send, which you haven't included in your question.

```
        len = ioStream.ReadByte() * 64;
        len += ioStream.ReadByte();
```

This is very unorthodox way to send/receive buffer length.

If you want 16 bit length value before each message, read two bytes to the array, call `BitConverter.ToUInt16` to make them into a number, and don’t forget to apply same conventions on the C++ side.